# How to find max & min value in java?(using loops and if else)

Tags: java, for-loop, if-statement

I want to input 10 marks for subjects from user.

and want print

1. total
2. max
3. min
4. average

I found total,max & average using this code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
class Example{
    public static void main(String args[]){ 
        Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
        int tot=0;
        int max=0;
        int min=0;
        double avg=0;
            
        for(int i =1;i<=10;i++){
             System.out.print("Input subject "+i+" marks : ");
             int marks=input.nextInt();
             tot+=marks;
             if(marks>max)
                max=marks;

        }
             avg=tot/10;
        System.out.println(tot);
        System.out.println(max);
        System.out.println(min);  //want to find
        System.out.println(avg);  
    }
}
```

Now how to find minimum of marks using **loops and if else** (is it possible?).

Comment: Surely you must have tried something? How can you get the max value but not the min value and if you have the total value how can you not easily calculate the average value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can edit your code like this,

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int tot = 0;
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    double avg = 0;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        System.out.print("Input subject " + i + " marks : ");
        int marks = input.nextInt();
        tot += marks;
        if (marks > max) {
           max = marks;
        }
        if (marks < min) {
            min = marks;
        }
     }
     avg = tot/10.0;
     System.out.println("total:" + tot);
     System.out.println("max:" + max);
     System.out.println("min:" + min);
     System.out.println("avg:" + avg);
 }
```

the output will be,

```
Input subject 1 marks : 50
Input subject 2 marks : 40
Input subject 3 marks : 12
Input subject 4 marks : 12
Input subject 5 marks : 15
Input subject 6 marks : 10
Input subject 7 marks : 85
Input subject 8 marks : 90
Input subject 9 marks : 52
Input subject 10 marks : 45
total:411
max:90
min:10
avg:41.1
```

Comment: @JoakimDanielson sorry you need to divide the `tot/10.0` then you will get what you expected.

Comment: Please can you explain  this code lines  `int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE;` and `int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;`

Comment: you are comparing max with your numbers, so if you use the minimum to compare it with other numbers eventually you will find the max, you can't initialize `max=0` because then we won't take negative numbers in to count.